# Rails 5 – assign model attribute and save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I've got a problem with assigning some value to model attribute and save it. I've tried a lot of ways, but none worked.

```
@rating = Rating.new(rating_params)
@rating.save
@rating.update_attribute(:ip_address, request.remote_ip)
```

or

```
@rating = Rating.new(rating_params)
@rating.ip_address = request.remote_ip
@rating.save
```

Nothing is working for me :-( Everytime I got NULL in my database for column `ip_address`

Comment: add ! to `@rating.save` like this `@rating.save!` you will get the error

Comment: Are you sure that `request.remote_ip` is not returning `nil`? Try adding `p "request.remote_ip is #{request.remote_ip}"` to your code before you attempt to assign it, and see what the logs show.

Comment: @JulienTASSIN it' doesn't help

Comment: @moveson I'm sure that request.remote_ip is not nil, because I'm printing it to console and there it is :-) "request.remote_ip is 127.0.0.1"

Comment: Can you use "save!" or "update_attributes!" methods? Then look at your console to see if there's an error.

Comment: Does the _#save_ method return `true`or `false`? (After assigning the _ip_address_.)

Comment: @user3216673  Did you add `ip_address` on your `rating_params`? Can you show your `rating_params` method?

Comment: @user3216673 Please help show the log when you save this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to debug in this situation.**

```
@rating = Rating.new(rating_params)
@rating.ip_address = request.remote_ip

#check is't valid to save: true || false
@rating.valid?

# if false, print error messages
p @rating.errors
p @rating.errors.full_messages

#either way you can try save without validation.
@rating.save(:validate => false)
```

Also, What data type of column `ip_address`. You can't save integer into string or vice versa.

`remote_ip` by default string class, if want to save as integer.

[Convert String Ip-address to Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244792/convert-ip-address-to-32-bit-integer-in-ruby)